# noUiSlider ES6 import

Tags: ecmascript-6, import, nouislider

I report here what I have reported here too: https://github.com/leongersen/noUiSlider/issues/971.

I've installed noUiSlider with ES6 imports (no webpack) as suggested in the official repo https://github.com/leongersen/noUiSlider#webpack.

So this is what I have.

```
// main.js
import 'nouislider';
```

```
//index.html

<html>

<body>

  <div id="slider"></div>

  <script src="js/bundle.js"></script>

  <script>
    var slider = document.getElementById('slider');

    noUiSlider.create(slider, {
      start: [20, 80],
      connect: true,
      range: {
        'min': 0,
        'max': 100
      }
    });
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

But it doesn't work and in the console I have the following message

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: noUiSlider is not defined.
```

If I insert `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/13.1.4/nouislider.min.js"></script>` instead of `<script src="js/bundle.js"></script>` it works.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `import 'nouislider'` in `main.js` imports the variable `noUiSlider` into *that* file.

By default, it does *not* export it into your `window` object. When you include the script from the CDN it *does* export into `window`, which is why it works there.

You could either:

- Move your slider initialization code into `main.js`
- Add `window.noUiSlider = noUiSlider` in `main.js`

Answer (score 5):

in main.js just write that import:

`import * as noUiSlider from 'nouislider/dist/nouislider.min';`